External WS is returning response with characters �+du� in Salesforce
When i consume an external ws, this response with especial characters like this: '�+du�רfz�B'
But Response in Postman its a valid Json without especial characters
Headers in postman 
Request and response in postman 
This code im using in saleforce
public virtual Callout createCallout(String metadataName){
        Endpoint__mdt mdt = soql to metadataName;

        this.mdt = mdt;
        //this is same that postmans header
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        request.setEndpoint(mdt.Named_Credential__c + mdt.Relative_Endpoint__c);
        request.setMethod(mdt.Method__c);
        request.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br');
        request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');//;charset=UTF-8
        request.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'br');
        request.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
        request.setHeader('User-Agent', 'Salesforce');
        request.setHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
        return new Callout(http, request, response);
    }

    public virtual HttpResponse sendCallout(Callout callout) {
        callout.response = new HttpResponse();
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){callout.response = callout.http.send(callout.request);}
        return callout.response;
    }

//This consume the ws
HttpResponse response = sendCallout(callout);
    sBody = Test.isRunningTest()? mdt.Response__c: response.getBody();//this return especial characters



If you compare the request HTTP headers Postman sends and the headers you send in Apex, it's likely you'll find a difference.

@identigral i compare the headers and put the same in apex, but the problem continue :'c

Please edit the question and show the request/response in Postman

Can you take a look at the headers in the response to see if you really got UTF-8 back as the character set? You could likely see it in the debug log. Example below.... ```
15:56:53.708 (708084839)|NAMED_CREDENTIAL_RESPONSE|NamedCallout[Named Credential Id=0XA4p000000Xa8g, Named Credential Name=MyNamedCredName, Status Code=200, Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8, Response Size bytes=784, Overall Callout Time ms=182, Connect Time ms=2
111

@identigral ok, im put the img of postman and apex

I had the same issue. Try simply removing the 'accept-encoding' header and your response should come through unencoded.
Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

thank you very much, it worked, you saved me <3
