Unexpected character ('�' (code 65533 / 0xfffd)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
I am making a POST call and receiving a 200, but getting the below error when I try to parse the response. The call works in Postman and I can read the JSON response. I am guessing its related to the response type contains the header 'Content-encoding: br'.
However, I am using the header, 'Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br' in my call.
Below are a full list of the response headers. Any ideas on how I can parse the response as JSON?
The expected response body would look like:
{
"status": "String",
"ssoURL": "String"
}



Duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/420773/external-ws-is-returning-response-with-characters-du-in-salesforce

Why allow the remote server to respond using compression if you are not prepared to decompress the response? Change the accept-encoding to only specify application/json...

@PhilW Thank you! I clearly misunderstood what 'accept-encoding' does. I thought it was required if the response would be encoded. I removed that header and it took care of the problem. Many thanks!

I recommend you add a self-answer to help later searchers.

I posted an answer on this post that had the same question
External WS is returning response with characters �+du� in Salesforce
If you do not need to receive an encoded response, simply remove the 'accept-encoding' header and you should receive plain JSON.
